# How to get Links to translated content in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I need to get the path to the translated content in Drupal8 and think `getLanguageSwitchLinks()` just doing this but I did not managed to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
$pfad = languageManager->getLanguageSwitchLinks('de', 'http://example.com/fr/produits');

print 'Pfad: ' . $pfad;
```

This should get me the path to the German version of http://example.com/fr/produits

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to use internal Uri or route. In your case you can try that :

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$url = Url::fromUri('internal:/produits', array (
    'language' => \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguage('de'),
));
$path = $url->toString());
```

For reference : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.3.x